# Old passport in UAE Visit visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, dubai, passport-renewals

Here is my situation:

I have my Indian passport with 3 more years validity which is never used.
It is a ECR *(Emigration Check Required)* status passport.

I received my UAE 90 days visit visa issued on 10 April 2016 but I just came to know that I need a ECNR *(Emigration Check Not Required)* status passport to travel UAE from India.
So I have to apply for a new ECNR Passport. Old passport will be cancelled. My UAE visit e-visa has my old passport number.

So in this case do I need to apply for another visa or can I travel with both passports in hand ?

Comment: You need a ECNR passport to _work_ in UAE. It doesn't matter if you are only a tourist.

Comment: Yes.. its true.. but only on papers.. tourists also denied in aiport actually

Answer (score 2):

It is extremely common to travel with cancelled passports because they contain a visa. They will punch the machine readable stripe of the personal data page of your old passport which makes it unusuable as a passport but your visa will be fine. You will present both passports on the border. Edit: you might want to explicitly state you need your passport back.

I have been travelling like this with a cancelled Hungarian passport containing a ten year B1/B2 USA visa since 2009 and a valid Hungarian passport as well (and a Canadian PR card and a NEXUS card. Yay, paperwork).

Here's a photo of my old passport, sensitive data blurred and the punch holes marked with red arrows -- all human readable data stays intact:

[image: cancelled passport]

Comment: thanksfoe your answer..my visa not stamped on my old passport.. it was a e-visa.. 2 A4 paper visa printout

Comment: Doesn't matter. As visible on the photo I just added the number of the old passport will stay intact -- just not in the machine scan region, see ZE4174(last two digits blurred) in the upper right corner.

Comment: Also, you might need to explicitly state you need your old passport back because of visa purposes.

Comment: yes I can see it.. thanks a lot for the quick response...